# it compiles but gives me an exception

Tags: java, swing

This program is supposed to take a sentence and return the number of uppercase letters, lower case letters, and digits. It compiles, asks for input, and returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at projects.projectzero.check(projectzero.java:16)
    at projects.projectzero.main(projectzero.java:10)
```

---

```
package projects;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class projectzero {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sentence = "", addToSentence = "";
        while (!addToSentence.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            addToSentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("input words or enter  stop to end program");
            sentence += addToSentence;
        }
        check(sentence);
    }

    public static void check(String input) {
        int upperCase = 0, lowerCase = 0, numbers = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
                upperCase++;
            else if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
                lowerCase++;
            else if (Character.isDigit(c)) numbers++;
        }
        System.out.println("the number of uppercase: " + upperCase + " the number of lower case : " + lowerCase + "the number of digits is: "
                + numbers);
    }
}
```

---

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The last available index in a `String` (or an array, or a `List`) is `length() - 1`, but you aren't stopping the `for` loop if `i` reaches `length()`.

Stop the iteration before `i` reaches `length()`.  Replace `<=` with `<`.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++ ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are zero based. So your loop must stop at `input.length()-1`

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++ ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `i < input.length()` instead of `i <= input.length()`.

**Edit** this works because indexing is zero-based: the 1st entry is at `i= 0`, the 2nd at `i=1`, etc. So the final entry is at `i=length() - 1`.